# Set focus for EditText in ListView in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, fragment, adapter

I checked all the possible solutions to handle the focus of EditText in a ListView.
I have a ListView in a fragment. The adapter of this ListView is composed by an ImageButton, an ImageView and an EditText. I want the EditText focusable.
I tried some solutions, one of these was:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    FileAdapter adapter;
    ListView lv;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new FileAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), list);

        lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if (position == 1){
                    lv.setItemsCanFocus(true);

                    lv.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
                    adapter.nome.requestFocus();
                }else{
                    if (!lv.isFocused()){
                        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
                        lv.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
                        lv.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                lv.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
            }
        });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Then in my XML file i have `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` in my ListView.

Here is my FileAdapter class:

```
public class FileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Files> {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    EditText nome;
    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<Files> list;    

    public FileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Files> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.homeadapter, list);

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homeadapter, null);    
        nome = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNomeFile);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Obviously i put here only useful part of my code, as i said before my adapter has also other elements but useless for the question.
The solution i tried doesn't work so i'm searching another.

Comment: use `OnItemClick` instead of `OnItemSelected`

Comment: @kaushik it doesn't work

Comment: do u need any `click event` for rows or only that `ImageView` and `EditText` ?

Comment: I didn't write this in my question cause i can do this after i know how to set the focus. Pratically if i press on the item i will go to another activity with details, if i press on ImageButton i can choose different actions. One of them is to rename the item. If i press it i want to do what i asked: put the focus on the EditText.

Comment: Fondesa I find a little error now... Try to change in Array adapter this: public FileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Files> list) for public FileAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Files> list) and change when you call adapter adapter = new FileAdapter(getActivity(), list); I can see now because the original adapter class use Activity not a context! Try this and say me! Good luck!

Comment: I tried it now, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I have the similar problem with my fragment... This is my fragment code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment_MainActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Declaration of classes
    Floor_Adapter FloorsAdapter;
    Floor_List Floors = new Floor_List();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Declaration of controls
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.building_view, container, false);
        TextView txtvHotelName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtvHotelName);
        ListView lvFloors = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvFloors);


        txtvHotelName.setText("Hotel");
        Floors.setFloorsArray();
        FloorsAdapter = new Floor_Adapter(getActivity(),Floors.getFloorsArray(),lvFloors);
        lvFloors.setAdapter(FloorsAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String A;
        TextView floor = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtvFloor);
        A = floor.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

And this my adapter code:

```
public class Floor_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Floor_Object>{
//Declaration of atributes
private ArrayList<Floor_Object> Floor_List;
private final Activity context;
private final  ListView lvFloors;

public Floor_Adapter(Activity context,ArrayList<Floor_Object> Floors_Array,ListView lvFloors) {
    super(context,R.layout.floor_layout,Floors_Array);

    this.context = context;
    this.Floor_List = Floors_Array;
    this.lvFloors = lvFloors;
}

public static class Floor_View{

    //Declaration of Atributes
    TextView FloorName;
    Button btnFloorRow;

    ImageView CheckImage;
    TextView NoChecks;

    ImageView BlockImage;
    TextView NoBlocks;

    ImageView DirtImage;
    TextView NoDirts;

    ImageView TroubleImage;
    TextView NoTroubles;

    ImageButton btnShowTasks;
    ImageButton btnShowRooms;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Declaration of Variables
    Floor_View rowView;
    LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if(ConvertView == null){

        rowView = new Floor_View();
        ConvertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.floor_layout,null,true);

        rowView.FloorName = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvFloor);
        rowView.btnFloorRow = (Button) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.btnFlooRow);

        rowView.CheckImage = (ImageView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCheck);
        rowView.NoChecks = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvCheckRooms);

        rowView.BlockImage = (ImageView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.ivBlockRooms);
        rowView.NoBlocks = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvBlockedRooms);

        rowView.DirtImage = (ImageView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.ivDirtRooms);
        rowView.NoDirts = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvDirtRooms);

        rowView.TroubleImage = (ImageView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.ivTroubleRooms);
        rowView.NoTroubles = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvTroubleRooms);

        rowView.btnShowTasks = (ImageButton) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.btnShowTasks);
        rowView.btnShowRooms = (ImageButton) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.btnShowRooms);


        ConvertView.setTag(rowView);
    }
    else
    {
        rowView = (Floor_View) ConvertView.getTag();
    }

    Floor_Object Floor = Floor_List.get(position);
    rowView.FloorName.setText(Floor.getFloorName());

    if(Floor.getNoChecks().equals("0")) {
        rowView.CheckImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        rowView.NoChecks.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        rowView.CheckImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        rowView.NoChecks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rowView.NoChecks.setText(Floor.getNoChecks());
    }

    if(Floor.getNoBlocks().equals("0")) {
        rowView.BlockImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        rowView.NoBlocks.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        rowView.BlockImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        rowView.NoBlocks.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rowView.NoBlocks.setText(Floor.getNoBlocks());
    }

    if(Floor.getNoDirts().equals("0")) {
        rowView.DirtImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        rowView.NoDirts.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        rowView.DirtImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        rowView.NoDirts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rowView.NoDirts.setText(Floor.getNoDirts());
    }

    if(Floor.getNoTroubles().equals("0")) {
        rowView.TroubleImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        rowView.NoTroubles.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        rowView.TroubleImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        rowView.NoTroubles.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rowView.NoTroubles.setText(Floor.getNoTroubles());
    }

    if(Floor.getNoBlocks().equals("0") && Floor.getNoDirts().equals("0") && Floor.getNoTroubles().equals("0")) {
        rowView.btnFloorRow.setClickable(false);

        rowView.btnShowTasks.setClickable(false);
        rowView.btnShowTasks.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_999999_50);
    }
    else{
        rowView.btnFloorRow.setClickable(true);
        rowView.btnFloorRow.setOnClickListener(OnShowTasksClickListener);

        rowView.btnShowTasks.setClickable(true);
        rowView.btnShowTasks.setOnClickListener(OnShowTasksClickListener);
        rowView.btnShowTasks.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_3a4b66_50);
    }
    rowView.btnShowRooms.setOnClickListener(OnShowRoomsClickListener);

    return ConvertView;
}

private View.OnClickListener OnShowTasksClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int position = lvFloors.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener OnShowRoomsClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int position = lvFloors.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
    }
};
}
```

You can see when I work with fragment it's mandatory to create control events in adapter... Just change  event of view and that it's your need, I think... I am waiting that sample helps you. If you need more info or help advice me, Good luck!

PD: I think this is your code that you need:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
FileAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new FileAdapter(getActivity(), list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
}


public class FileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Files> {
private final Context context;
private ArrayList<Files> list;
private final ListView Lv;    

public FileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Files> list,ListView lv) {
    super(context, R.layout.homeadapter, list);

    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.Lv = lv;
}

public static class RowView{

//Declaration of Atributes
EditText Nome;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    RowView rowView;
    LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if(ConvertView == null){

        rowView = new RowView();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.homeadapter, null);

        rowView.nome = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNomeFile);
    }

    rowView.nome.setOnItemSelectedListener(ItemSelecteListener);

    return convertView;
}

private View.setOnItemSelectedListener ItemSelecteListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
        public void onItemSelected(View view) {

            final int position = lvFloors.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());

            if (position == 1){
                lv.setItemsCanFocus(true);

                lv.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
            }else{
                if (!lv.isFocused()){
                    lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
                    lv.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
                    lv.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
};  
}
```

Comment: I tried to use something like this but i think (i don't know, i can mistake) that it isn't useful for my case actually. Anyway thanks for have tried.

Comment: If you want to capture any event this is your solution! :D

Comment: Fondesa see the PD in my editing post and say me! Good luck! :D